# spring batch debug logs

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am unable to log the spring batch logs in spring boot application which uses JPA. Here is the properties file configuration (application.properties). I want to see if application has created spring batch table from the logs.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

#show sql statement
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
#show sql values
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=debug
log4j.category.org.springframework.jdbc.core = debug
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true


log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.batch=DEBUG
```

And here are the logs :

```
[2m2017-10-23 15:10:33.624[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10092[0;39m [2m--
-[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m 
 [36mo.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql]
[2m2017-10-23 15:10:35.988[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10092[0;39m [2m--
-[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m 
[36mo.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql] in 2363 ms.
```

Comment: Those logs say that they were.  What more are you expecting?

Comment: Create SQL logs because I don't see table in database

Comment: Spring doesn't have that capability I believe.  You'd need to look at your db logs.  The scripts were definitely run though.  You sure you're looking at the right db?

Comment: Thanks. It was binding issue in AWS mysql

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the following things:

If you are providing datasource in Spring properties, make sure the setting are correct and you are checking at correct place

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username = dbuser
spring.datasource.password = dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

If you are binding a service, make sure the setting are fine and and it is correctly bind, and spring is using that database. If you are using PCF, check this [link](https://pivotal.io/platform/pcf-tutorials/getting-started-with-pivotal-cloud-foundry-dev/connect-a-database).